# Sizing issue in MDIForms

Tags: c#

iam having an MDI form,in which i placed a form.i have some issues while resizing

1. how to set the maximum for the the mdichild so that it cannot be resized to the entire
   container if i selects maximize
2. is it possible to put anything apart from a form inside the container( i am using a third
   party component dotnetmagic,i want to create a content using it and like to place it in the
   mdicontainer)

Thnx in advance

Answer (score 1):

1. Set the normal MaximumSize/MinimumSize property of the MDIChild Form, or see http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;327824 if it doesn't work.
2. No. Consider using WPF and Canvas, if you want to create a custom drawing environment.